# Click event on Fusioncharts in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview, fusioncharts

I have a StackedBar 2D graph using FusionCharts in native iOS app where I am plotting a bar chart.
On click of single bar plot, I have to redirect user to previous screen by calling a native function.
I am using "link" attribute in FusionCharts as:
data:

```
{
    "link": "j-showAlert";
}
```

And in the script tag of FusionCharts I have written a showAlert function.
But click event is not triggering.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if function call is blocked or not allowed in Xcode Application Debugger.

Alternatively, you can use FusionCharts API events and methods (***dataPlotClick***) for this. You can also get details respective to dataPlot clicked via event parameters.

```
"events": {
  "dataPlotClick": function(ev, props) {
    showAlert();
    function showAlert() {
        alert("Data Plot Clicked: " + props.toolText);
    }
  }
```

Please check this [JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/x8MDc/530/).

To know more about this event, please check this documentation page: http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events.html#event-dataplotClick

Answer (score 0):

```
    "events": {
      "dataPlotClick": function(ev, props) {
        //write your code
      }
   }
```

Comment: Can you describe how this code answers the question?

Comment: Please elaborate in detail, how this helps the OP